# Exception thrown when rendering a dynamic label WebControl with the AssociateControlID

Tags: c#, .net, rendering, web-controls

I get an exception when calling a web service which dynamically builds HTML elements at run-time and returns the rendered elements as a string.

The following error occurs on the RenderControl() method call:

**System.Web.HttpException: Unable to find control with id 'txtCertificate' that is associated with the Label 'lblCertificate'.**

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

// Create System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel (container)
Panel pnlFRow1 = new Panel();
pnlFRow1.CssClass = "f-row";

// Create System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox
TextBox txtCertificate = new TextBox();
txtCertificate.ID = "txtCertificate";
txtCertificate.CssClass = "f-input f-input-full";

// Create System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
Label lblCertificate = new Label();
lblCertificate.ID = "lblCertificate";
lblCertificate.CssClass = "f-label f-label-full";
lblCertificate.AssociatedControlID = txtCertificate.ID;
lblCertificate.Text = "Certificate:";
Panel pnlCertificate = new Panel();
pnlCertificate.CssClass = "f-label f-label-full";

// Binding child controls to parent controls
pnlFRow1.Controls.Add(lblCertificate);
pnlFRow1.Controls.Add(pnlCertificate);
pnlCertificate.Controls.Add(txtCertificate);

// Render control
pnlContent.RenderControl(writer);

// Return rendered HTML
return writer.InnerWriter.ToString();
```

I tried placing the line `pnlFRow1.Controls.Add(lblCertificate);` after the line `pnlCertificate.Controls.Add(txtCertificate);` thinking that this might be an issue where the order matters, however this causes the same error.

The `AssociatedControlID` attribute is a must have in order to have the `Label` WebControl render as an actual `<label>` element and must be displayed before the input control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to inherit the Label class, and replace the RenderBeginTag method with something that's more to your liking.  If you nest the Label class it should keep in the local context and stop it leaking out into the rest of your application

For example:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
        public class Label : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label {
        public string For = null;
        public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
            AddAttributeIfExists(writer, "ID", ID);
            AddAttributeIfExists(writer, "For", For);
            writer.RenderBeginTag("Label");
        }
        private void AddAttributeIfExists(HtmlTextWriter writer, string name, string value) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                writer.AddAttribute(name, value);
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        Panel test = new Panel() { ID = "PanelTest" };

        TextBox txtCertificate = new TextBox() { ID = "txtCertificate" };
        Label lblCertificate = new Label() { ID = "lblCertificate", Text = "Certificate", For = txtCertificate.ClientID };

        test.Controls.Add(lblCertificate);
        test.Controls.Add(txtCertificate);

        test.RenderControl(writer);
        string teststring = writer.InnerWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Instead of using `AssociatedControlId`, you can now use a custom `For` property which will do the same thing.  Also note how the Label class is nested inside your page class, so it doesn't interfere with other pages.

Unfortunately, as we discovered in the first version of this answer, if you try to use `.Attributes["for"]` without the `AssociatedControlId`, .NET will convert the `<Label>` to a `<span>`, so the above example should get around this.

Comment: The only issue with adding the attribute is that the `Label` WebControl will not be rendered as a `<label>` element

Comment: Hmm, strange, .NET changes it to a span tag if there's no AssociatedControlID.  Another option would be to extend the Label webcontrol locally, see my updated answer

Comment: You're on to something here, the only issue is that it no longer renders any other properties. For example the `ID` property in your example isn't rendered.

Comment: You could just add the ID property in the override.  The problem is the `base.RenderBeginTag()` is the method that adds the attributes, but this is also the same method that adds the `<span>` tag instead of the `<label>` tag, so we can't call it if we want to guarantee we'll always get a `<label>`.  See my updated answer

Comment: I understand your approach, but there must be a better way to dynamically retrieve the values of those properties without having to specify the name of the properties.

Comment: Yes, quite possibly.  However, my personal opinion is that there's only so much you can do to force a web control to fit the mould you want it to.  After a point, you do so much extra coding it's not even worth the result - and you might as well use a custom control from the beginning.  Or, just use a string.  There may well be a better answer to the question out there, of course.